# Merge Ruby Hash values with same key

Tags: ruby

Is this possible to achieve with selected keys:

Eg

```
h = [
  {a: 1, b: "Hello", c: "Test1"},
  {a: 2, b: "Hey", c: "Test1"},
  {a: 3, b: "Hi", c: "Test2"}
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {a: 1, b: "Hello, Hey", c: "Test1"}, # See here, I don't want key 'a' to be merged
  {a: 3, b: "Hi", c: "Test2"}
]
```

**My Try**

```
g = h.group_by{|k| k[:c]}.values
OUTPUT =>
  [
    [
      {:a=>1, :b=>"Hello", :c=>"Test1"},
      {:a=>2, :b=>"Hey", :c=>"Test1"}
    ], [
      {:a=>3, :b=>"Hi", :c=>"Test2"}
    ]
  ]

g.each do |v|
  if v.length > 1
    c = v.reduce({}) do |s, l|
      s.merge(l) { |_, a, b| [a, b].uniq.join(", ") }
    end
  end

  p c #{:a=>"1, 2", :b=>"Hello, Hey", :c=>"Test1"}
end
```

So, the output I get is

```
{:a=>"1, 2", :b=>"Hello, Hey", :c=>"Test1"}
```

But, I needed

```
{a: 1, b: "Hello, Hey", c: "Test1"}
```

**NOTE:** This is just a test array of HASH I have taken to put my question. But, the actual hash has a lots of keys. So, please don't reply with key comparison answers

**I need a less complex solution**

Comment: Please state the question in words, at the beginning. The question is not implied by a single example. You do not wish to keep the value of the key `:a` in `h[1]`? `h` is not the best name for an array.

Comment: If `{a: 4, b: "Hello", c: "Test1"}` where to exist I am assuming the output should be the same as it is now correct? Since "Hello" already exists in the grouping? As of right now this is unclear and unhandled and will result in `{a: 1, b: "Hello, Hey, Hello", c: "Test1"}` because `uniq` will be comparing `"Hello Hey"` to `"Hello"`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I understand your suggestion. But, this is just a way to put my question. The actual code is huge and has large number of keys in the hash

Comment: @engineersmnky I don;t understand what you are trying to say. May be my question is bit unclear. But, you may try the code in an `irb` console. I don't know where you would get a value as `"Hello Hey"` without a `,`

Comment: @Abhi sorry for the typo but the question still remains you have a uniqueness check in you code that is likely to fail almost every time. I was enquiring as to the expected output if that additional Hash existed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see a simpler version of your code. To make it fully work, you can use the first argument in the `merge` block instead of dismissing it to differentiate when you need to merge `a` and `b` or when you just use `a`. Your line becomes:

```rb
s.merge(l) { |key, a, b| key == :a ? a : [a, b].uniq.join(", ") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider this option, but I don't know if it is less complex:

```
h.group_by { |h| h[:c] }.values.map { |tmp| tmp[0].merge(*tmp[1..]) { |key, oldval, newval| key == :b ? [oldval, newval].join(' ') : oldval } }
#=> [{:a=>1, :b=>"Hello Hey", :c=>"Test1"}, {:a=>3, :b=>"Hi", :c=>"Test2"}]
```

The first part groups the hashes by `:c`

```
h.group_by { |h| h[:c] }.values #=> [[{:a=>1, :b=>"Hello", :c=>"Test1"}, {:a=>2, :b=>"Hey", :c=>"Test1"}], [{:a=>3, :b=>"Hi", :c=>"Test2"}]]
```

Then it maps to merge the first elements with others using [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

Comment: Worth pointing out that `{:a=>4, :b=>"Hello", :c=>"Test1"}` will result in `{:a=>1, :b=>"Hello Hey Hello", :c=>"Test1"}` because `uniq` will be comparing `"Hello Hey"` to `"Hello"` so maybe `h.group_by { |h| h[:c] }.transform_values {|v| v.uniq {|h| h[:b]} }.values....`

Answer (score 1):

```
h.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:c]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(b: "#{o[:b]}, #{n[:b]}") }
end.values
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>"Hello, Hey", :c=>"Test1"},
  #    {:a=>3, :b=>"Hi", :c=>"Test2"}]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o.merge(b: "#{o[:b]}, #{n[:b]}") }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. The first block variable holds the common key. I’ve used an underscore for that variable mainly to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation. See the doc for definitions of the other two block variables.

Note that the receiver of `values` equals the following.

```
h.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:c]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(b: "#{o[:b]}, #{n[:b]}") }
end
  #=> { “Test1”=>{:a=>1, :b=>"Hello, Hey", :c=>"Test1"},
  #     “Test2=>{:a=>3, :b=>"Hi", :c=>"Test2"} }
```